# Weblogic - Python script in order to deploy many applications

Tags: weblogic

I have a strange problem. I deploy many ear and war files with a Python script. However, during the second app deployment, I always get the following error message:

```
Property APPLICATION.CONF.REFRESH not found
```

And in the other MS - DOS window where the script is executed, I get this warning / error:

```
<Warning> <JNDI> <BEA-050001> <WLContext.close() was called in a different thread than the one in which it was created.>
```

Both messages seem to me erroneous.

The message with Property is runnig the whole time and nothing works anymore.

What could be my error?

Here is my script:

```
connect(username, pwd)
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/')
cd('AppDeployments')
deploy(fileName, path, targets='AdminServer')
save()
activate()
disconnect()
exit()
```

This script gets executed 5 times in a row.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899565/bea-050001-wlcontext-close-was-called-in-a-different-thread-than-the-one-in may be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure that the message "APPLICATION.CONF.REFRESH" is a WLST or weblogic message. Maybe an application message fired when the application is started. You can ignore the warning about closing the jndi context, known issue at Oracle.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Regarding the APPLICATION.CONF.REFRESH message I thought the same, too. Regarding the jndi message I can really ignore it?

Comment: One more question: As soon as I install all my packages manually via the GUI, everything works great, but when I do it via the script, the error message in my console runs and runs. We use a seperate plan.xml file, maybe I have to deploy this somehow, too. I never do that manually or via the CLI. Can I somehow specify the plan.xml to use when deploying the app?

Comment: The deploy() function has an option to deploy an application with a deployment plan. See this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/reference.html#1024285)

Comment: Thank you very much. With the option planPath the automatic installation is possible. As I figured out, I am able to install it via the GUI but not via CLI. If I try it via the CLI without planPath it never works and I always get the following error message, sysing: Error while Activating changes. : com.factory.factorycommons.wax.exception.WAXException: Invalid configuration No backend defined. Maybe, you know why that is happening? Installing it via planPath is accepted.